# HIDL interface inheritance

Tags: android, inheritance, hal, hidl

I am trying to extend the implementation of HAL functionality. It seems that once HAL interface is published, we cannot made any changes in that version. So I tried to do interface inheritance by referring here https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/hidl-java#extensions.

IA.HAL File

```
interface IA{
Amethod();
};
```

ClientService.Java file

```
IA ia = IA.getService(true);
//ia is not null. Working fine
```

For extension, I created a new HAL file which involves interface inheritance as below.

IB.HAL file

```
import IA;
interface IB extends IA{
Bmethod()
};
```

ClientService.Java file

```
IA ia = IA.getService(true);
//ia is not null. Working fine
IB ib = IB.castFrom(ia);
**// ib is null. Issue**
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A HAL server is identified by its interface name and its instance name. Could it be that the server providing `IA` is still running?

You might have the following setup at the moment:

| Binary | Interface | Instance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `/system/bin/ia-service` | `IA` | `"default"` |
| `/vendor/bin/ib-service` | `IB` | `"default"` |

The default for `getService` is to use `"default"` as instance.

Solutions:

1. Make sure `ia-service` is not started.
2. Provide your HAL with a new instance name (e.g. `"new"`) by calling `registerAsService("new")` in `ib-service` and get the instance with ```getService("new", true)````in your client.